# JQuery load() function not working on live server but working on localhost

Tags: jquery, load

The code below worked on localhost but did not work online

```
$("#PstsubmitChcReport").click(function(){
    $("#response").load("submitServiceReport/");
});
```

Somebody please help in solving the problem

Comment: Check the network tab of the console to see the exact error. The URL is most likely different on the server due to changed folder paths.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of [Same-origin Policy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

There are some Workarounds. You can [follow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).